# Function of temperature compensation (Tcm / tCom) Pin of MG811 CO2 sensor

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-analysis, sensor, temperature

I have the MG811 CO2 sensor and can use it in genrell. But for me the function of the temperature compensation (Pin "Tcm / tCom") is not quite understandable.

Here is the circuit of the sensor: 
[image]
And the [link](http://image.dfrobot.com/image/data/SEN0159/CO2b%20MG811%20datasheet.pdf) to the Datasheet of the sensor itself.

Does the value serves for further processing in software or is it only used as information (Compensation already takes place in the hardware)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The temperature value can be used for compensation by external analog or digital means. The EMF follows the data sheet nominally, so the temperature and humidity dependencies are not extreme- chances are it’s not necessary in some applications.

The “hardware” is just an electrolytic (Nernst) cell and a heater, nothing sophisticated.